# Check against a DB when an SMS is received on an Android phone

Tags: android, database, sms

I want to develop an app that checks against a DB what to do after receiving an SMS, that is, it will receive a message and depending on the content or number or both, it performs different actions, it occurred to me that the best way to do this was by checking against a DB am I right? And if so, can this be done? I have no experience on Android dev.

Answer (score 1):

A database is certainly one way to do this. Basically, any data storage mechanism that can be queried will work, be it an SQLite database of trigger strings, or simply a `String[]` array. It simply depends how many actions you wish your system to understand, and how complex they are.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are many answers about SMS receiving stuff, i'm sure you can get these answers by searching.

And here i will give you some tips about that. There're two ways to observe on SMS receiving.

1.Register a BroadcastReceiver to listen on "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"(google ti), and when your android receive a SMS message, it will call your BroadcastReceiver.

2.Observe on SMS database. Actually it's not database, it's Content Provider. In android OS, there're many content providers, you can register ContentObserver, whenever the SMS database changed, the OS will call your code.